# How to use nested 'with' keyword

Tags: javascript

Can I use 'with' keyword with more than one object at same time? I tried to nest them, but failed. So what should be the best way to do this?

```
var firstVariable ={a: 0, b: 0, c:0};
var secondVariable ={qw :98, ety :367, hg: 356};

with(firstVariable){
    with(secondVariable){  
        a = qw;
        b = ety;
        c = hg;
    }
}
```

Comment: How did it fail? Can you please include the code that 'tests' your expected outcome?

Comment: FYI `with` is dangerous to use. See Douglas Crockford's explanation: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/

Comment: You may look into this. http://javascript.info/tutorial/with-operator

Comment: You should avoid [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with).

Comment: The "best" way is by simple assignment: `firstVariable.a = secondVariable.b`. Why do you want to do it some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell the second nested `with` is in the scope of the first. So it does work. I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FWbt7/) that demonstrates that. However, in my gut, this whole thing seems pretty wrong.

Answer (score 5):

<s>No, the second `with` changes the scope to `secondVariable` and you can't access the first one.</s> It will work as Drew Larson showed, but you shouldn't do it.

`with` is not recommended anyway and temporary variables should be used instead, so the example code would be written this way (assuming `firstVariable` and `secondVariable` are so cumbersome you don't want to just do `firstVariable.a = secondVariable.qw`):

```
var firstVariable ={a: 0, b: 0, c:0};
var secondVariable ={qw :98, ety :367, hg: 356};

var o1 = firstVariable;
var o2 = secondVariable;

o1.a = o2.qw;
o1.b = o2.ety;
o1.c = o2.hg;
```

Comment: there is noting here answers "with", but your answer will work.